# Mirth Connect and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, mirth

I'm new to Mirth Connect and was hoping to send and receive messages to/from RabbitMQ. Mirth Connect doesn't natively support this, only JMS. I've tried installing the RabbitMQ JMS client, but get exception `RMQJMSException: invalid stream header: 4C616220`. I get the impression that even if I succeeded, there still isn't interoperability between JMS clients and AMQP clients.

It looks like I'll have to go down the JavaScript Reader / JavaScript Writer route, which strikes me as very inefficient. Does anyone have experience in connecting to RabbitMQ in such a manner?